# Jack and Jill and destinationDir

Tags: android-jack-and-jill

Google has officially released Jack & Jill as mentioned on their [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2014/12/hello-world-meet-our-new-experimental.html) .

But if I use the following property :

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'xxx'
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 162
    versionName 'xxx'
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.multidex.MultiDexTestRunner"
    manifestPlaceholders = [ cappId:"xxx",cappLog:"false" ]
    useJack = true
}
```

I get the following error

```
Error:Cannot get property 'destinationDir' on null object
```

I have no problem if I comment use Jack property

I know it's an experimental tool but do you know how can I fix that ?

Comment: did you got the solution...

Comment: I disabled it for now

Comment: how you did can you please do some post

Comment: Like I said in my post: `I have no problem if i comment useJack property`

Comment: oh okay thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score -3):

Are you using retro-lambda, dagger2 or any other annotation processing library? In that case you need to manually specify the processor.

See this thread: https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda/issues/71

Comment: could you give some details

Comment: Hi @MinaFawzy, like this: https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt#markdown-header-additional-configuration

No guaranties ;)

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question